# Is Wikidata a reliable KB for genomic and drugs annotations?

Tags: sequence-annotation, public-databases, data-management

I'm looking for a Linked Open Data approach to annotate a dataset with human genome and drugs information.

According to the [Linked Open Data cloud](http://lod-cloud.net/), there are a lot of interconnected `RDF` vocabularies devoted to life sciences but, unfortunately, a lot of them seem out of date.

I recently found [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/):

> Wikidata is a free and open knowledge base that can be read and edited
>   by both humans and machines.

It seems exactly what Linked Data should be and it seems continuously updated. At a first sight, it covers very well genomic and drugs knowledge.

Does Anyone know if Wikidata is a reliable source for genomic and drugs annotation?

Answer (score 1):

The question is what you mean with "reliable". For bacterial genome annotations there is one Wikidata based platform called [WikiGenomes](http://wikigenomes.org/) ([publications](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28365742)).

Comment: Hi konrad, thanks for your answer and welcome to Bioinformatics Stack Exchange. If you would like your answer to collect more votes, it is helpful to add more information about any links that you provide. What does WikiGenomes provide in addition to annotations? How reliable do you consider it to be?

Comment: Thank you konrad. With "reliable" I mean regularly updated and curated from trusted sources. PS: I'm looking for human genome annotations. I'm going to specify that also in the question